# Hover over a pre - how to highlight a single line with plain CSS?

Tags: html, css, pre

I have some `<pre>` blocks.

Would it be possible, using just CSS, to highlight single lines when hovering over them?

**== Update ==**

Here is some sample code:

```
<pre>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
    {
       printf("Hello World");
       return 0;
    }
</pre>
```

When lines become longer it would be useful to have them highlighted when hovering.

The source file can't be read via PHP, or I'd split it into separate `<pre>` lines, with a trivial `pre:hover` CSS.

`pre:nth-child` is not a solution, because code lines are not "children" in the CSS sense.

`pre:first-line` works, but of course just for the first line.

**== Update 2 ==**

Since CSS seems to be limited to `first-line`, and thanks to Zeke suggestion, I found an almost simple way to have what I want.

HTML:

```
<pre id="raw">
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
    {
       printf("Hello World");
       return 0;
    }
</pre>
<!-- 1×1 transparent PNG for the onload -->
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR42mP4/x8AAwAB/2+Bq7YAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" onload="PreHover()" />
```

CSS:

```
#pre div:hover {
    background: #ff0;
}
```

Vanilla Javascript:

```
function PreHover() {
    var output = '';
    var preBox = document.getElementById('raw');
    var txt = preBox.innerHTML.split('\n');
    for(var x=0;x<txt.length-1;x++) {
        output = output + '<div>'+txt[x]+'</div>';
    }
    preBox.innerHTML = output;
}
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Marco_Bernardini/odyxae12/3/)

Comment: Can you elaborate your question. such as can you Provide some code?, What exactly you mean to single lines?  is it some sort of line of code ? Also let us know what efforts you did ?

Comment: @NileshMahajan - I added more infos to my post.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is possible without JavaScript.

Comment: not sure what you want but what about `pre:first-of-type` or `pre:nth-of-type` ?

Comment: @dippas - `first-of-type` and `nth-of-type` are perfect for a list or a table, but not for raw text.

Comment: If, as you say, you have no control over the HTML then what you're looking to achieve is not going to be possible.

Comment: What leaves me perplexed is that if `first-line` can understand where the first line of the text inside the `<pre>` ends, why it's not possible to make the same for the other lines?

Comment: In your [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Marco_Bernardini/odyxae12/1/) You had a small mistake in the **js** code you had.
Put this `var txt = htm.split('\n');` in place of `var txt = htm.split('\\n');` in your jsFiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This will help you wrap **div** for each line

```
var txt = $('pre').html().split("\n");
var output = "";
for(var x=0;x<txt.length-1;x++)
    output = output + "<div>"+txt[x]+"</div>";
}
$('pre').html(output);
```

> You can write one line **css** then for highlighting:

```
pre div:hover { background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2); }
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/xhqr5eky/)

**Note**: This requires **jQuery**

**Optional**: Add `white-space:nowrap` to prevent wrapping each line

> **Why** do this?

Because if just have `<pre>`, it will be a DOM element containing just ***text*** inside it, on which you can make changes as a whole, and not line by line.

To have **much better** control over every line, build a new DOM element by manipulating the text contained in `<pre>` with **pre** containing many **div** each of which contains one line of text. And now you can master each and every **div**